# How to print directly, without Print Dialog in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, flowdocument

I just want to know how I can print a flow document without showing Print Dialog in WPF.

Thanks for help…

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the PrintDialog class without showing the dialog (without calling ShowModal)

Answer (score 17):

This is one of the ways you can change default printer or change other settings:

```
using System.Printing;  //add reference to System.Printing Assembly
                        //if you want to modify PrintTicket, also add
                        //reference to ReachFramework.dll (part of .net install)
...

var dlg = new PrintDialog();

dlg.PrintQueue = printer; // this will be your printer. any of these: new PrintServer().GetPrintQueues()
dlg.PrintTicket.CopyCount = 3; // number of copies
dlg.PrintTicket.PageOrientation = PageOrientation.Landscape;

dlg.PrintVisual(canvas);
```

Comment: Unfortunately if you try to print to file there is a dialog, anyone know the solution for print to file?

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
PrintDialog dialog = new PrintDialog();
dialog.PrintVisual(_PrintCanvas, "My Canvas");
```