# How to Print without displaying a print popup in WPF

Tags: wpf

```
private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            PrintDialog dialog = new PrintDialog();
            if (dialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                StackPanel stpanel;
                stpanel = PrintStakPanel;
                stpanel.Measure(new Size(Double.PositiveInfinity, Double.PositiveInfinity));
                Size grdSize = stpanel.DesiredSize;
                Point grdPoint = new Point((dialog.PrintableAreaWidth - grdSize.Width) / 2, (dialog.PrintableAreaHeight - grdSize.Height) / 2);
                stpanel.Arrange(new Rect(grdPoint, grdSize));
                Grid.SetRow(stpanel, 0);
                dialog.PrintVisual(stpanel, "Cinema Ticket");

            }
        }
```

Comment: Format your code in a proper way. IF you post like this, no one will help.

Comment: Please add additional details of what you need help with instead of framing the entire question in the title

Comment: in my Application thats a Cinema Application that is being developed in WPF, I have Film Tickets in a grid to be printed.
Now the problem is that I dont want to open any Dialog(eg Print Dialog), i just want to click on "Print Ticket" button and all the tickets in the grid should be printed without asking for Page Layout etc

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PrintDialog` without doing a `ShowDialog()` call....the currently set printer settings will just be used when you call `PrintVisual`.

To do something more sophisticated, you can programmatically define the printer settings by using a `PrintTicket`.

See here for more details:

- [How to print directly, without Print Dialog in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995559/how-to-print-directly-without-print-dialog-in-wpf)
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.printticket.aspx

Comment: Can i get some knowledge about PrintTicket Class.
i m not getting whatever given in MSDN..
Please tell something about implementation of PrintTicket.

Answer (score 0):

do not call dialog.ShowDialog() in your code.